What do you call the error model of swapping observations not labels?
I am working on a classification problem and have reason to believe that the only error the classifier makes is due to swapping the predictions of some cases with those of other, unobserved cases. This swapping occurs at a rate $ r $, independent of the class. Formally:
$$
P(\text{Predicted}=c \mid \text{Actual}=c) = \underbrace{(1 - r)}_{\text{not swapped}} + \underbrace{r \cdot P(\text{Actual}=c)}_{\text{swapped with another unobserved case of the same class}}
$$
This differs from a constant error model where predictions are swapped to a different class at a rate that is independent of the class (i.e., label noise completely at random).
I've searched the literature but couldn't find a description of this model. What are common names for such a model and for the parameter $r$?

I have vaguely come across something like this in the context of information theory and error correcting codes, where the concept of "permutation noise" comes into play (i.e. a bit being randomly flipped). While this relates more to information/data transmission than classification, it might still align with your situation: the classifier performs well, but the "channel" delivering the results swaps the labels at a rate $r$, causing the observed errors.
